how to change UID of user in image/pod
I launched Retool software in Openshift.
I have error in pod:

"user running container is not the expected user, retool_user (uid 1001) in retool_user_group (gid 1001)".

Pod has different UID 1001260000. As I understood Retool requires user - retool_user & group - retool_user_group.
I changed UID & GID in Dockerfile with commands
RUN groupmod -g 1001260000 retool_user_group
RUN usermod -u 1001260000 retool_user 

But I received image with size over 300 GB. How to rebuild image with lower size or solve  problem with UID of retool_user? My Dockerfile:
FROM tryretool/code-executor-service:latest
RUN groupmod -g 1001260000 retool_user_group
RUN usermod -u 1001260000 retool_user 

Question is updated.

Add your Dockerfile and the command that you use to build / run

@Mate added dockerfile

The UID and GID of the running user are defined at deployment time within OpenShift. The 1001260000 (which is a overstated high number, this is how you can detect it 99% of the cases) is coming from a concept called user_namespaces (man7.org).
To overwrite the running user in OpenShift, you can define the UID as part of your resource manifest under containers[].securityContext.runAsUser like:
     containers:
     - name: container-name
       securityContext:
           runAsUser: 1001
       image: quay.io/...


You can find more details about it at https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/a-guide-to-openshift-and-uids.

I overwrote the running user UID to 1001260000, pod was created, but software still gives me error above. I set securityContext: runAsUser: 1001260000. This UID is requirement in my namespace.
